# In Evans PDE, trace-zero functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, approximation, trace

In Evans 275~277 trace-zero function theorem proof,

u $\in$ ${{W^1}^,}^p(R_+^n)$, $u$ has compact support in $\bar R_+^n$,

$Tu = 0$ on $\partial R_+^n$ = $R^{n-1}$

Then since $Tu = 0$ on ${{{R^n}^-}^1}$, there exist functions $u_m \in C^1(\bar R_+^n)$ such that

$u_m$   $\to$  u in  ${{W^1}^,}^p(R_+^n)$ and $Tu_m=u_m|_{R^{n-1}} \to 0$ in $L^P(R^{n-1})$.

In here, my question is **Why these $C^1(\bar R_+^n)$ functions exist**

Comment: I do not have the book here, however a sequence fulfilling the first condition exists by the fact that $C^\infty$ and thus also $C^1$ are dense in $W^{1,p}$, which should have been shown earlier. The second then should follow from the definition of the trace operator, which is continuous as a map from $W^{1,p}$ to $L^p$.

Comment: I know that when U is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$, $C^\inf (\bar U)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}$, but in this situation,Are these conditons satisfied?

Comment: Okay, if this is only known for bounded $U$, there is still some work. The construction is rather standard: You can find a function $\phi_R:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which is smooth (or at least $C^1$), equal to $1$ on $B_R(0)$, equal to $0$ outside of $B_{2R}(0)$ and for which the derivative is bounded by something like $C/R$ for a $C$ independent on $R$. Now if for some nice $U$ you take $v \in C^1(U)$ close to $u|_U$ in $W^{1,p}(U)$ where $B_{2R}(0) \cap \mathbb{R}^n_+ \subset U$, then $\phi_R  v$ is somewhat close to $u$ in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n_+)$. Can you take it from here?